# Log of Saha equation and ionization state

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, astrophysics

Why do I take the logarithm of the [Saha formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation) when calculating the ratio between ionized and neutral atoms of an element? What is the physical meaning?

Comment: I normally see it w/o log, so can you give some references as to where you've seen it with the logarithm?

Comment: https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/phys/particle-physics/star-n-planet-formation-dam/documents/Courses/AstrophysikIHS2017/Solution_exercise_sheet3.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Saha equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation) relates one ionization state to another ionization state (often the ground state):
$$
\frac{n_{i+1}}{n_i}\sim T^{3/2}\exp\left[-\varepsilon/k_BT\right]
$$
where $n_i$ are the $i$th ionization state populations and the other variables take their normal meaning.

To see the reason why one would take the logarithm, note that $\log[x]\geq0$ for $x\geq1$ and $\log[x]<0$ for $x<1$. Since the Saha equation gives relative populations of two ionization states, then taking the logarithm can show more quickly which state is more populous:
$$
\log\left[\frac{n_{i+1}}{n_i}\right]\to
\begin{cases}
>0 & \text{if }\, n_{i+1}>n_i \\
\sim0 & \text{if }\, n_{i+1}\sim n_i \\
<0 & \text{if }\, n_{i+1}<n_i
\end{cases}
$$
So any positive value means the higher state is more populated than the lower state, while the negative values indicate the lower state is more populated.

Comment: Don't see how comparing with zero is a simpler process compared to comparing with one.

Comment: @WeijunZhou whether it is a simpler process or not, which is probably subjective, is irrelevant to the fact that it does happen and the answer I gave is the why.